# unix shell with property file reading

Tags: shell, unix

Below is my code

```
. appl.properties
products=$PRODUCTS
arr=$(echo $products | tr "," "\n")
for x in $arr
do
   with="${x}SUBPRODUCTS"
   subproducts=$(echo $with)
   arr2=$(echo $subproducts | tr "," "\n")
   for w in $arr2
   do
     echo "> $w"
   done
done
```

my property file will be of format

```
PRODUCTS=A,B,C
ASUBPRODUCTS=D,E,F
```

i have to read from products properties and form the another key `ASUBPRODUCTS`.

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: i have to split the products entry with delimiter "," and that value i have to use in other key value as shown . I will split and get the value as A and that value i have to use in other entry "ASUBPRODUCT" to get the value. the problem is i cant able to get the value for the subproducts

Comment: Please add a "what I get" and a "what I expect" paragraphs...

Comment: ok I get "A" when i split and iterate in loop   and what i expect is value of subproducts "D,E,F"

Comment: This is what I get running your code: ´> ASUBPRODUCTS
> BSUBPRODUCTS
> CSUBPRODUCTS
´

Comment: but i need D,E,F the values of ASUBPRODUCTS.

Answer (score 1):

With this code:

```
. appl.properties

for x in $( echo $ASUBPRODUCTS | tr "," "\n") ; do
    echo "x=$x"
done
```

you should get this output:

```
x=D
x=E
x=F
```

Comment: yeah if i harcode as "ASUBPRODUCTS" the values are coming properly, but  "ASUBPRODUCTS" will be formed dynamically in the code. refer the code   line     with="${x}SUBPRODUCTS"

Answer (score 0):

Don't source (.) the properties file, read it instead.

```
while IFS== read var value; do
  echo var=$var
  echo value=$value
done < appl.properties
```

Since it's not really clear from the question what you actually want to do with these values, I'm just echoing them.